# Entity Framework: Saving two new entities at once

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I'm working with Entity Framework 5 and a MySQL DB and I'd like to save two new related entities at once:

```
Address address = data.Addresses.Create();
address.Street = ...
data.Addresses.Add(address);

Person person = data.Persons.Create();
person.FirstName = ...
data.Persons.Add(person);

data.SaveChanges();
```

But it fails. When I call SaveChanges after I added the entity Address it works. But I want to avoid two roundtrips to the DB, when one should be enough.

Best regards,
Torsten

Comment: This should work, although I use a different syntax: `Address address=data.Addresses.Add(new Address());` I think you should show us more code.

Comment: Has Person as property object Address? If person has the object address too, the data.Addresses.Add(address) it wouldn't be necessary. Which error throws EF to you?